# If ΣXn and ΣYn both are convergent then prove ΣXnYn is also divergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am practicing some questions on convergence and divergence and stumble onto this problem. 
Can anyone provide me some hints on how should I solve this question?

I already read a similar question on stackexchange but in the answers they have taken Xn=Yn, but I want to know, is the same true if both the series are different.

Comment: But is it true though?

Comment: I guess, it would be contradictory.

Comment: What about $X_n=Y_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}$?

Comment: Of course, when stating a problem here, it helps to include all the hypotheses.  For example, perhaps the original included the condition that $X_n, Y_n$ are nonnegative.